# Create lobby using socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vuejs2, socket.io

for my school project i have to recreate Secret Hitler game using socket.io/express/vuejs2.

And at the moment I'm stuck at the part where i should create lobby that other people should be able to join. I used [rooms](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/) for the lobby, but then i realized that it's not what i need. What i though of is when person creates a lobby, a name will be assigned to that specific lobby so other user will be able to join that lobby by inserting the name of it or using the link which would look something like that `http://mygame.com/?lobby=ABCD`. But if i got socket.io rooms correctly, i wont be able to do that, because you can't create unique rooms. Or I'm just dumb and haven't figured that out yet.

So my question is how could i implement lobbies based on my idea using socket.io and expressjs? What documentation should i read?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4

I know it is a zoom app but it will give you a basic idea on how to create rooms with node.js

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm watching it right now. Will let you know if it helped or not!